# InvalidParameterException: Addon version specified is not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I've been trying to deploy a self managed node EKS cluster for a while now, with no success. The error I'm stuck on now are EKS addons:

**Error: error creating EKS Add-On (DevOpsLabs2b-dev-test--eks:kube-proxy): InvalidParameterException: Addon version specified is not supported, AddonName: "kube-proxy", ClusterName: "DevOpsLabs2b-dev-test--eks", Message_: "Addon version specified is not supported" }
with module.eks-ssp-kubernetes-addons.module.aws_kube_proxy[0].aws_eks_addon.kube_proxy
on .terraform/modules/eks-ssp-kubernetes-addons/modules/kubernetes-addons/aws-kube-proxy/main.tf line 19, in resource "aws_eks_addon" "kube_proxy":**

This error repeats for coredns as well, but ebs_csi_driver throws:

**Error: unexpected EKS Add-On (DevOpsLabs2b-dev-test--eks:aws-ebs-csi-driver) state returned during creation: timeout while waiting for state to become 'ACTIVE' (last state: 'DEGRADED', timeout: 20m0s) [WARNING] Running terraform apply again will remove the kubernetes add-on and attempt to create it again effectively purging previous add-on configuration**

My main.tf looks like this:

```
terraform {

  backend "remote" {}

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 3.66.0"
    }
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 2.7.1"
    }
    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = ">= 2.4.1"
    }
  }
}

data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks-ssp.eks_cluster_id
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks-ssp.eks_cluster_id
}

provider "aws" {
  access_key = "xxx"
  secret_key = "xxx"
  region     = "xxx"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "xxx"
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
    token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
  }
}
```

My eks.tf looks like this:

```
module "eks-ssp" {
    source = "github.com/aws-samples/aws-eks-accelerator-for-terraform"

    # EKS CLUSTER
    tenant            = "DevOpsLabs2b"
    environment       = "dev-test"
    zone              = ""
    terraform_version = "Terraform v1.1.4"

    # EKS Cluster VPC and Subnet mandatory config
    vpc_id             = "xxx"
    private_subnet_ids = ["xxx","xxx", "xxx", "xxx"]

    # EKS CONTROL PLANE VARIABLES
    create_eks         = true
    kubernetes_version = "1.19"

  # EKS SELF MANAGED NODE GROUPS
    self_managed_node_groups = {
    self_mg = {
      node_group_name        = "DevOpsLabs2b"
      subnet_ids             = ["xxx","xxx", "xxx", "xxx"]
      create_launch_template = true
      launch_template_os     = "bottlerocket"       # amazonlinux2eks  or bottlerocket or windows
      custom_ami_id          = "xxx"
      public_ip              = true                   # Enable only for public subnets
      pre_userdata           = <<-EOT
            yum install -y amazon-ssm-agent \
            systemctl enable amazon-ssm-agent && systemctl start amazon-ssm-agent \
        EOT

      disk_size     = 10
      instance_type = "t2.small"
      desired_size  = 2
      max_size      = 10
      min_size      = 0
      capacity_type = "" # Optional Use this only for SPOT capacity as  capacity_type = "spot"

      k8s_labels = {
        Environment = "dev-test"
        Zone        = ""
        WorkerType  = "SELF_MANAGED_ON_DEMAND"
      }

      additional_tags = {
        ExtraTag    = "t2x-on-demand"
        Name        = "t2x-on-demand"
        subnet_type = "public"
      }
      create_worker_security_group = false # Creates a dedicated sec group for this Node Group
    },
  }
}

module "eks-ssp-kubernetes-addons" {
    source = "github.com/aws-samples/aws-eks-accelerator-for-terraform//modules/kubernetes-addons"

    eks_cluster_id                        = module.eks-ssp.eks_cluster_id

    # EKS Addons
    enable_amazon_eks_vpc_cni             = true
    enable_amazon_eks_coredns             = true
    enable_amazon_eks_kube_proxy          = true
    enable_amazon_eks_aws_ebs_csi_driver  = true

    #K8s Add-ons
    enable_aws_load_balancer_controller   = true
    enable_metrics_server                 = true
    enable_cluster_autoscaler             = true
    enable_aws_for_fluentbit              = true
    enable_argocd                         = true
    enable_ingress_nginx                  = true

    depends_on = [module.eks-ssp.self_managed_node_groups]
}
```

What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

K8s is hard to get right sometimes. The examples on Github are shown for version `1.21` [1]. Because of that, if you leave only this:

```
    enable_amazon_eks_vpc_cni             = true
    enable_amazon_eks_coredns             = true
    enable_amazon_eks_kube_proxy          = true
    enable_amazon_eks_aws_ebs_csi_driver  = true

    #K8s Add-ons
    enable_aws_load_balancer_controller   = true
    enable_metrics_server                 = true
    enable_cluster_autoscaler             = true
    enable_aws_for_fluentbit              = true
    enable_argocd                         = true
    enable_ingress_nginx                  = true
```

Images that will be downloaded by default will be the ones for K8s version `1.21` as shown in [2]. If you really need to use K8s version `1.19`, then you will have to find the corresponding Helm charts for that version. Here's an example of how you can configure the images you need [3]:

```
  amazon_eks_coredns_config = {
    addon_name               = "coredns"
    addon_version            = "v1.8.4-eksbuild.1"
    service_account          = "coredns"
    resolve_conflicts        = "OVERWRITE"
    namespace                = "kube-system"
    service_account_role_arn = ""
    additional_iam_policies  = []
    tags                     = {}
  }
```

However, the CoreDNS version here (`addon_version = v1.8.4-eksbuild.1`) is used with K8s `1.21`. To check the version you would need for `1.19`, go here [4]. TL;DR: the CoreDNS version you would need to specify is `1.8.0`. In order to make the add-on work for `1.19`, for CoreDNS (and other add-ons based on the image version), you would have to have a code block like this:

```
enable_amazon_eks_coredns             = true
# followed by
  amazon_eks_coredns_config = {
    addon_name               = "coredns"
    addon_version            = "v1.8.0-eksbuild.1"
    service_account          = "coredns"
    resolve_conflicts        = "OVERWRITE"
    namespace                = "kube-system"
    service_account_role_arn = ""
    additional_iam_policies  = []
    tags                     = {}
  }
```

For other EKS add-ons, you can find more information here [5]. If you click on the links from the `Name` column it will lead you straight to the AWS EKS documentation with the add-on image versions supported for the EKS versions currently supported by AWS (`1.17` - `1.21`).

Last, but not the least, a friendly advice: **never ever** configure the AWS provider by hard-coding the access key and secret access key in the `provider` block. Use named profiles [6] or just use the default one. Instead of the block you have currently:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "xxx"
  secret_key = "xxx"
  region     = "xxx"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "xxx"
  }
}
```

Switch to:

```
provider "aws" {
  region   = "yourdefaultregion"
  profile  = "yourprofilename"
}
```

---

[1] https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-eks-accelerator-for-terraform/blob/main/examples/eks-cluster-with-eks-addons/main.tf#L62

[2] https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-eks-accelerator-for-terraform/blob/main/modules/kubernetes-addons/aws-kube-proxy/local.tf#L5

[3] https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-eks-accelerator-for-terraform/blob/main/examples/eks-cluster-with-eks-addons/main.tf#L148-L157

[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-coredns.html

[5] https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-eks-accelerator-for-terraform/blob/main/docs/add-ons/managed-add-ons.md

[6] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

Comment: Thank you! And of course, I don't hardcode that, I'm just doing test runs and I'm too lazy to place them as env vars :)